# Where to place the Commit block of a complex NodeJS MySQL Transaction?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql, nodejs-server

I have the following code in NodeJS which works well to;

1. Begin a MySQL transaction;
2. Create an audiopost;
3. Update an audiopost.
4. Check to see if tag1 exists and if not, create it and insert into a tag table. If it does exist simply insert it to the tag table.
5. Commit the transaction;

But now I'd like to also check for tag2 and tag3 also.
Unfortunately, I can't figure out where and how to place the commit block
in order to keep it all as a single transaction.

If I put it just before the closing of the check for "tag1" the code won't get as far as "tag2" and "tag3".  But if I put it after then the closing brackets to the connection queries are in the wrong place. Here's the code;

```
var mysql   = require("mysql");
var express = require("express");
var connection = require("../database");


 var createAudiopost = function(req, res, next){
     
 var title = req.body.title;
 var userid = req.body.userid;
 var opid = req.body.opid; 
 var tag1 = req.body.tag1;
 var tag2 = req.body.tag2;
 var tag3 = req.body.tag3;
     
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  
    connection.query('INSERT INTO ?? (title,userid,opid) VALUES (?, ?, ? )', ['audioposts',title,userid,opid], function(err, result) {
     if (err) { 
      connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
      });
    }

    var audioname = userid + '-' + result.insertId + '.m4a';
    var newid = result.insertId;    
    console.log("newid: "  , newid  );
    
    connection.query('UPDATE ?? SET audioname=? WHERE audioid = ?',  ['audioposts',audioname,newid], function (error, result, fields) {
      if (err) { 
        connection.rollback(function() {
          throw err;
        });
      }  
      
      if (tag1)  {  
        connection.query('SELECT tagid FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?', [tag1], function (error, result, fields) {
                    
                  if (err) { 
                    connection.rollback(function() {
                      throw err;
                    });
                            }                           
                            const tagid1 = result[0].tagid;
        if (result < 1) {   

            connection.query('INSERT INTO tags SET tagname = ?', [tag1], function (error, result, fields) {
                      if (err) { 
                    connection.rollback(function() {
                          throw err;
                            });
                                }   
                                
                        console.log("lets see this ridiculous result", result);
                                                            
                        const tagInsertId = result.insertId;
                    
                connection.query("INSERT INTO entitytag SET audioid = ?, tagid = ?, userid = ?", [newid, tagInsertId, userid], function (error, result, fields) {
                      if (err) { 
                        connection.rollback(function() {
                          throw err;
                            });
                              }  

                connection.commit(function(err) {
                if (err) { 
                  connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                  });
                }
                 console.log('success!');
                 newid = result.insertId;
                 res.json({
                                "title" : title, 
                                "userid" : userid,
                                "opid" : opid, 
                                "insertid": newid
                        }); //resjson success               
                    }); //commit              
                }); // insert entitytags
            }); // insert tags          
          } // if row
          
          else {                                            
                connection.query("INSERT INTO entitytag SET audioid = ?, tagid = ?, userid = ?", [newid, tagid1, userid], function (error, result, fields) {              
              if (err) { 
                connection.rollback(function() {
                  throw err;
                        }); //err
                        } //err 

                connection.commit(function(err) {
                if (err) { 
                  connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                  });
                }
                 console.log('success!');
                 res.json({
                                "title" : title, 
                                "userid" : userid,
                                "opid" : opid, 
                                "insertid": newid,
                                "tag1": tag1
                        }); //resjson success               
              }); //commit  
            })  // insert entitytag2
          }
        }); //select tagid
      }//tag1
    }); //update
  }); //insert
}); //begin transaction
}   //createaudiopost
   module.exports = createAudiopost;
```

Any suggestions for how I can complete such a complex transaction? I basically need to repeat the entire section of `if (tag1)` for tag2 and tag3.

Comment: The first thing I would do to solve this is to leave callback hell. Use a [mysql package that supports promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) and rewrite your code accordingly. It will be much easier to organize your code that way.

Comment: Ok. So I'm experimenting with promises, but how do I get the insertId of the returned rows? Here's what I tried ; mydb.query( str_sql_1 )
    .then( rows => {
        row_a = rows;
  var newid = row_a[0].insertId; 
        return  mydb.query( str_sql_2 );
    } )

Comment: If I do `const res = await connection.query('INSERT INTO table (\`colname\`) VALUES (123);');` I can then do `console.log(res[0].insertId);` to get the new ID. I suggest using `await` because that way you can write "synchronous" code and won't get into scope troubles.